# Find out div class

Tags: php

could you help me please? Where can I find div class (Easy Digital Downloads plugin) in Wordpress?
Appereance -> Edit Theme -> ?

`<div class="wpb_wrapper">`

Answer (score 0):

CSS classes in plugins come straight from the plugins. It's safer to add CSS to a child theme (or your current theme's "Custom CSS" area if it has one) targeting the plugin's class. If you edit the plugin files, anytime you update the plugin, your changes will be overwritten.

Please note, the Edit Theme functionality is also rather insecure and is best turned off. It too suffers from the same issue - if you make changes directly and then update your theme, your changes are lost. (And it's important to keep plugins and themes up to date as updates often contain security patches.)

Comment: maybe i ask the wrong answer, I would like to delete some class. It is all about the cart where I don't want to some fields.

Comment: Right, I understood your question. It's far easier to add CSS to affect that class, instead of actually removing it. To actually remove the class, you could either use JS to remove it only for users who have JS turned on (usually not an ideal solution), or fork the plugin and then you would be responsible for maintaining the plugin (also usually not ideal). That is why creating your own CSS to style the existing class would be the easiest solution.